# Trying to redirect users to root_path if not admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I have a link in a navigation bar which i want users to be able to access if they are admin. If they are not admin i want it to redirect to the root path. The page that I dont want regular users to get at is the login screen for Active admin. Ive done some digging and cant see where i can override the controller for active admin. I was thinking of two way's to achieve this. First, I would like to redirect the user from my application controller or secondly from the active admin session controller (which i cant find). This is the link in my application view item

```
<li class="nav-item">
      <%= link_to 'Admin' , new_admin_user_session_path, class:"navbar-brand" %>       
 </li>
```

This is my application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base


end
```

I think the easiest way is from the application controller. I just can figure out how to link up the nav link with a method in the application controller Any help would be much appreciated

EDIT I found something where i can edit the session controller in routes.rb below

```
class ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController 
   before_action :auth_user
 def auth_user
    redirect_to personal_trainers_path unless current_user.try(:admin?)
  end
end
```

But now I am getting First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty. It work when im not admin but when i am i get the error

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a before action. For example:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :auth_user

  def auth_user
    return if current_user # or whatever logic to authorize them
    redirect_to root_path # fallback if not authorized
  end
end
```

There are many flavors of this. For example the common Doorkeeper library includes an action for this:

```rb
before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!
```

I'd recommend using Doorkeeper or something similar so you're not writing your own auth functionality from scratch.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I edited my answer and tried the before action auth but now im getting a 401 error. Im not even getting a stack trace. Its basically telling me it doesnt exist

Comment: is there a way of doing it in the nav bar item within the application controller ?